# Validating constructor parameters

Tags: c#, exception, constructor

I have a class with two constructors:

```
MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj)
MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj, MyObj secondaryObj)
```

`primaryObj` is always required. `secondaryObj` is not. Obviously you can call `MyObjGroup(myObj)` or `MyObjGroup(myObj, null)` and end up with the same result.

What I first considered doing was in my first ctor, checking for `null` on `primaryObj` and throwing a `ArgumentNullException`. I would also need to do this in my secondary ctor, duplicating the code, so I considered moving this to the property setter.

```
private MyObj _primaryObj;
public MyObj PrimaryObj
{
    get {return _primaryObj;}
    private set
    {
       if(value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "PrimaryObj cannot be null");
        _primaryObj = value;
    }
 }
```

however, the name of the parameter in the property is `value` while in the ctor it is called `primaryObj`. Another ctor (heaven forbid) may call it something else so there is no guarantee you have the correct name.

what is the recommended course of action here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value in your first constructor, and have the second constructor do a pass-through to it in order to avoid duplicate code.

```
public MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj) 
{
    if(primaryObj == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "PrimaryObj cannot be null");
}

public MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj, MyObj secondaryObj) 
    : this(primaryObj)
{
    SecondaryObj = secondaryObj;
}
```

Comment: is it really `base(primaryObj)` not `this(primaryObj)`?

Comment: Don't you mean `: this(primaryObj)` on the second ctor, rather than `base` ?

Answer (score 2):

I always put the logic in as few constructors as possible, so I would do this:

```
public MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj) : this(primaryObj, null) { }

public MyObjGroup(MyObj primaryObj, MyObj secondaryObj) {
    if (primaryObj == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "PrimaryObj cannot be null");
    }
    SecondaryObj = secondaryObj;
    PrimaryObj = primaryObj;
}
```

Comment: I actually considered this as this is similar to how I structured these before adding in the validation. In my example this would work, but I've actually over-simplified the question compared to my actual scenario.